# The speed of the function about loading pictures in java

Tags: java

I test use two methods to load more than 2m size picture in my application.

```
private void loadImages() {
        long currentTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
        MediaTracker mediaTracker = new MediaTracker(this);
        images = new HashMap<String, Image>();
        for (Iterator iterator = model.getAllImages().iterator(); iterator
                .hasNext(); mediaTracker.addImage(tempImage, 0)) {
            String filename = (String) iterator.next();
            try{
            tempImage=ImageIO.read(Game.class.getResourceAsStream(filename));
            }catch(Exception e){

        }
            //URL imageURL = getClass().getResource(filename);
        //  tempImage = getImage(getCodeBase(), imageURL.toString());
            images.put(filename, tempImage);
        }

        try {
            mediaTracker.waitForID(0);
        } catch (InterruptedException interruptedexception) {
        }
        System.err.println(System.currentTimeMillis()-currentTime);
    }
```

My testing result shows the `ImageIO.read()` is twice slowly than the `getImage()`.Could someone explain me why? Waiting for you reply.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that two functions work in two different ways.

`ImageIO` is guaranteed to return you an image that can be painted immediately, where as `getImage` will return you a reference to a possible image which may be loaded at some time in the future, hence the reason you see paint methods that need `ImageObserver`

This would explain much of the difference between `BufferedImage` and `Image`.  `BufferedImage` allows you direct access to things like the pixel and color model data

Comment: Thank for you reply.I can understand most your answer.But what does "hence the reason  paint methods needs ImageObserver" mean?

Comment: Look at something like Graphics2D.drawImage. This last parameter is a ImageObserver (which is luckily implemented by most UI components). This is used to tell the Graphics engine when image data is available to be painted. You have to remember, the original premise was Imges would be loaded off networks (with slow modems), so they needed away to track the progress so as not to slow the paint cycle. ImageIO was introduced in JDK 1.4 with the intention of providing a more "direct" loading mechanism

Comment: So if load big image data,is the ImageIO better than the other?

Comment: @user1456: If you load a large image, then you'll need to do this on a thread off of the EDT, the Swing event thread. 1+ to Mad.

Comment: @user1456170 it comes down to when you want the image to available. If you must paint the image immediately, the I'd use ImageIO (personally, I'd use ImageIO all the time) or you want access to the image data.

Comment: @user1456170 ImageIO also supports a pluggable architecture making it vastly more useful. You can't load digital RAW photos with getImage, but you can get a plugin for ImageIO